# Insert with PHP into Microsoft SQL Server 2014 german Umlaute issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to Insert data with PHP into a Microsoft SQL Server 2014.
I've never worked with this one.
I've made the PHP file in combination with a MYSQL DB and there everything worked fine.
The MYSQL DB was set on UTF-8 so I didn't have any problems with german umlaute.

On the SQL Server I get very strange characters instead of the german umlaute.

For Example:
Austria is in german "Östereich" the value in my DB look like "Ã–sterreich".

I didn't found a solution for my problem. I've tried to change the Collation to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

Comment: How did you change the collation and have you verified its taken affect on the individual tables involved and then tried a new insert? Take a look at the collation of one of the specific tables involved

Comment: can you provide code sample of how you're trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your php file is encoded with `UTF-8`. You can try changing the encoding of the php file to `latin1`.

As `UTF-8` allows less common caracters to be more than 8 bits long (8, 16, 24 or 32 bits are allowed), so it can happen that the conversion from UTF-8 to a strictly 8bit encoding as latin1 "fails". Less common caracters take up more than one 8-bit space, for example äöü. Thats the reason you're seeing `Ã–` instead `Ö`.

Of course a better solution would be if your database would accept `UTF-8`.

Comment: I use sqlsrv in PHP to connect with my DB. I found a solution where I can give a Charset param with the connection "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8" and this worked!  LINK: http://www.johnro.net/2012/07/25/php-sqlsrv-problems-with-utf-8-values-set-your-characterset-option/

Comment: nice! then it would be best if you would create a new answer to your question and mark it as accepted